# check if there is a word repeated at least 2 or more times. (Regular Expression)

Tags: regex, perl

Using Regular Expression,

from any line of input that has at least one word repeated two or more times.

Here is how far i got.

/(\b\w+\b).*\1

but it is wrong because it only checks for single char, not one word.

input: i might be ill

output: < i might be i>ll

<> marks the matched part.

so, i try to do (\b\w+\b)(\b\w+\b)*\1
but it is not working totally.

Can someone give help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
(\b\w+\b).*\b\1\b
```

greedy algorithm will ensure longest match.  If you want second instance to be a separate word you have to add the boundaries there as well.  So it's the same as

```
\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b
```

Comment: It breaks for `hey you hey how are you doing today ? are you happy ?`

Comment: it matches "hey you hey" as expected.  See it yourself here: https://regex101.com/r/rV4nO2/1

Comment: Yes but it doesn't matches other words which are occurring more than once. for example `you`

Comment: The question is if there is a word repeated twice or more.  Not find all the words repeated more than once.

Comment: I see, well OP mentioned **atleast one word**, _from any line of input that has at least one word repeated two or more times._ Need more clarification on question.

Answer (score 0):

To check for repeated words you can use `positive lookahead` like this.

**Regex:** `(\b[A-Za-z]+\b)(?=.*\b\1\b)`

**Explanation:**

- `(\b[A-Za-z]+\b)` will capture any word.
- `(?=.*\b\1\b)` will lookahead if the word captured by group is present or not. If yes then a match is found.

**Note:-** This will produce repeated results because the word which is matched once will again be matched when regex pointer ***captures it as a word***.

You will have to use programming to strip off the repeated results.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xU2xU2/2)**

Answer (score 0):

`Positive lookahead` is not a must here:

```
/\b([A-Za-z]+)\b[\s\S]*\b\1\b/g
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
\b([A-Za-z]+)\b     # match any word
[\s\S]*             # match any character (newline included) zero or more times
\b\1\b              # word repeated
```

[**REGEX 101 DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/pI1vF4/2)